# Inserción MongoDB con Python cada segundo

Tags: python, mongodb

El sistema trabaja con Python y MongoDB con PyMongo.

Mediante un requests recibo los datos de una URL que consulto cada segundo. Este script se ejecuta cada segundo sin límite de tiempo y a continuación realizo un insert en MongoDB.

No trato los datos para optimizar tiempo ya que me interesa almacenarlo todo. Recibo un array que, de momento, tiene 4 elementos (y en el futuro puede tener cientos), y se almacenan en Mongo como elementos independientes. Es decir, cada vez que realizo una lectura se realizan 4 inserts.

Como podría hacer para realizar estos inserts "simultaneos" o crear varios procesos que se ejecuten de forma simultanea para que realmente se obtengan datos cada segundo y pueda llegar a trabajar con cientos de elementos?

Código actual:

```
def get_values():   
  r = requests.get('URL', auth=('USER', 'PASSWORD'))    
  result = r.json()         
  lengthResult = len(result)

  for i in range(lengthResult):     
      result[i]['date'] = time.time()

  result_id = db.movements.insert(result)

  print(result_id)

  threading.Timer(1.0, get_values).start()

get_values()
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que estamos iniciando el primer proyecto con Python y Mongo y no tenemos gran experiencia.

Ejemplo de lo que guardo:

`[{"id":"0CF3EE00B221","name":"B4","desc":"","loc":{"lat":40.495860,"lng":-3.699990,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":87485,"rss":{"F45EAB0C0EC7":-82,"F45EAB0C1B0C":-78,"F45EAB0C1B67":-79,"F45EAB0BF97E":-75}},{"id":"0CF3EE007DF1","name":"B1","desc":"","loc":{"lat":40.495880,"lng":-3.700082,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-81,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-88,"F45EAB142A61":-65,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-85,"F45EAB08AAAD":-84,"F45EAB0C1B0C":-66,"F45EAB0C1B67":-78,"F45EAB0BF97E":-74}},{"id":"0CF3EE007E7F","name":"B3","desc":"","loc":{"lat":40.495864,"lng":-3.700000,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C0ED5":-87,"F45EAB142A61":-87,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-81,"F45EAB08AAAD":-85,"F45EAB0C1B0C":-73,"F45EAB0C1B67":-78,"F45EAB0BF97E":-73}},{"id":"0CF3EE008022","name":"B2","desc":"","loc":{"lat":40.495870,"lng":-3.699812,"levelId":0,"prec":3.75},"lrrt":0,"rss":{"F45EAB0C14C7":-69,"F45EAB0C0ED5":-85,"F45EAB142A61":-81,"F45EAB0C0EC7":-85,"F45EAB08AAAD":-50,"F45EAB0C1B0C":-86,"F45EAB0C1B67":-79,"F45EAB0BF97E":-80}}]`

Comment: Por favor, identa el código correctamente. En cuanto a lo de realizar *"inserts simultáneos"* para que terminen en menos de 1 segundo, ¿acaso esperas que los datos sean *coherentes* en un tiempo fijado?¿no sería mejor usar una base de datos relacional?

Comment: Disculpa, he intentado identar ahora bien el código. Es necesari oque estos datos sean coherentes ya que están asociados a una latitud/longitud en ese preciso instante. ¿Por que crees que sería mejor una base de datos relacional? He editado con un ejemplo de lo que guardo.

Comment: Disculpa pero creo que mongo no es exactamente la solución porque aunque es rapido al consultar datos, es algo lento en el tema inserciones

Comment: @RicardoD.Quiroga por "desgracia" es el sistema que ha "tocado". Por curiosidad, que sistema utilizarías?

Comment: No es que sea lento, el problema es que no te garantiza que el dato insertado sea visible en todos los nodos en un tiempo prefijado. Por tanto, ¿qué objetivo tiene insertar más rápido los datos? Si te importa mucho que los datos insertados estén consolidados antes de insertar los siguientes, entonces mongo no es la solución. Si quieres velocidad y un sólo nodo no es capaz, añade más nodos y reparte la carga. Si necesitas poder relacionarlos para geoposicionarlos, es que necesitas una base de datos relacional.